# C# Excluding related values from a list (LINQ)

Tags: linq, listbox

Is there an exact opposite action to "**join**" in linQ to SQL? I want to display just the results that do not fulfill the inner **join** constraint from a query. I wanna do it just in one query. Here's an example of it's use (http://img165.imageshack.us/img165/4940/liststj3.jpg).

Comment: Resize your image -- it doesn't show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falvarez's roles:

```
Roles.Where(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.Name == "falvarez"));
```

Roles that falvarez doesn't have

```
Roles.Where(r => !r.Users.Any(u => u.Name == "falvarez"));
```

Project each role into an object that knows whether falvarez is in that role

```
Roles.Select(r => new
  {
    FalvarezInRole = r.Users.Any(u => u.Name == "falvarez"),
    Role = r
  });
```

In the case that the role object doesn't have a users property, simply substitute a query that filters users by role in the place of r.Users

Answer (score 1):

Bilal Haidar has an [explanation](http://bhaidar.net/cs/archive/2007/08/01/left-outer-join-in-linq-to-sql.aspx) on how to do a left outer join.  Use this strategy and add a where condition to check where the object on the right hand side is null.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Zip here:

http://www.codeplex.com/nextension

EDIT:  might be better off doing "where !Collection.Contains(s.ID)" ...